# ngCordova barcode scanner is providing Object Object in the scannedData

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner, ngcordova

I am new to Cordova. I am trying to scan a QR code by referring to this [document](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/). When I do that in `alert`, it is providing `[object Object]` in scanned data. Anyone have idea on this.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
$cordovaBarcodeScanner
  .scan()
  .then(function(barcodeData) {
    console.log(barcodeData);
    alert(barcodeData);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

   $cordovaBarcodeScanner
  .encode(BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "http://www.nytimes.com")
  .then(function(success) {
    alert(success);
  }, function(error) {
    // An error occurred
  });

   },false);
```

Can anyone tell me what is the use of `encode` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you you get a scanned bar code (or qr code) data in `.then` block, you get an object (hash) of data. If you want to see it in the alert box then you have to stringify it:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(barcodeData));
```

Since `$cordovaBarcodeScanner` plugin works only on physical devise, you don't want to use `console.log`.

Regarding `.encode` method. It is currently not supported. So, there is no point of using it. The documentation also mentions this fact. So, just remove that part of your code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  $cordovaBarcodeScanner
    .scan()
    .then(function(barcodeData) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(barcodeData));
    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: thanks buddy it worked, do we have any option to change appearance of viewfinder.

Comment: What do you mean by `viewfinder`? The look and feel of scanner camera?

Comment: ya..it is showing like scanning barcode that red single line

Comment: Nope. You can't style it, unless you're willing to go into native coding.